# Is it possible to call windows service or process from Web Application?

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, windows-services

I want to call my custom windows service running on particular client machine from my Web application on button click. How can I do this?

Comment: This is a very low quality question. Please read [ask]

Comment: One does not _"call"_ a Windows Service by default.  Unless you have already coded in say a named pipes host connection; shared memory; TCP or perhaps hosting WCF, you are out of luck

Comment: How can you say that this is low quality question. This is the requirement to accomplish and I need a solution.

Comment: @Krutikapatel dont be offended, This forum has variety of users so everyone differs from others opinion, This may be your requirement but in your point of view its clear to you but for others it may not that much clear, So requesting you to provide any more details like what exactly you need and code sample would be better. If you want some ideas then please be more specific to provide any solution. Thanks!.

Comment: @RajeshB _"opinions"_ doesn't come into it, rather [ask].

Comment: @MickyD I agree mate.

Comment: I got the solution. Please find it in answer. Thanks MickD and all other team members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution and it works. Please find below steps.

1. Created Self-Hosted WCF service that call window services/processes
2. Call this WCF service from your web application

Please find below link for more details:
https://techinqueincsharp.blogspot.com/2019/05/open-clients-machine-local-file-from.html